# Can anyone explain one step of derivation in a branching process example?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I am reading the branching process example from chapter 0 of Probabilities with Martingales by Williams.

What confused me is the part between equation 0.9(c) and 0.9(d) on page 10 and 11. What does the matrix G and H mean? What does the author mean by "nth power of the matrix corresponding to f" where f here is a moment generating function?

The relevant section is pasted below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goal is to find a formula for the $n$-fold composition of $f$ with itself. This is difficult to do directly from the definition, so the author uses a clever trick.

The idea is that $f$ is a fractional linear transformation, and for every fractional linear transformation there is a corresponding matrix. Explicitly, if $T(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ then the corresponding matrix is $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$. For $f$ we have $a=0,b=p,c=-q$, and $d=1$, so the matrix corresponding to $f$ is $\begin{bmatrix}0&p\\-q&1\end{bmatrix}$.

Composing fractional linear transformations corresponds to multiplying matrices, so a formula for $f\circ\cdots\circ f$ can be found by finding a formula for the powers of the matrix corresponding to $f$. This can be done by diagonalizing the matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you also explain how is 0.8(c) derived?

Comment: That should probably be a separate question, since I think some definitions from the pages before what you've included are needed.

Comment: Not a problem! Thanks for your answer!!

Comment: I was reading your comment, trying to make sense of some details. Can you explain the relationship between a formula for f∘⋯∘f and diagonalizing the matrix?

Comment: This is what the author's doing on the top of page 11. If $A=SDS^{-1}$ with $D$ diagonal, then $A^n=SD^nS^{-1}$, and $D^n$ is easy to compute (just raise the diagonal entries to the $n$th power). Then use the correspondence between matrices and fractional linear transformations to translate this into a formula for $f\circ\dots\circ f$.